# Windows 8 Client for the SHOUTcast server

Tags: c++, http-headers, httpwebrequest, windows-store-apps, shoutcast

[These app](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11308/SHOUTcast-Stream-Ripper) can get a Shoutcast Metadata.

In some cases have an exception "The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine".

Request example:

```
GET http://173.244.215.162:8300/;stream.nsv HTTP/1.1
GET: / HTTP/1.0
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: WinampMPEG/5.09
Host: 173.244.215.162:8300
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

response:

```
ICY 200 OK
icy-notice1: <BR>This stream requires <a href="http://www.winamp.com/">Winamp</a><BR>
icy-notice2: SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.8<BR>
icy-name: 100Hitz - Top 40
icy-genre: Various
icy-url: http://www.100hitz.com
content-type: audio/mpeg
icy-pub: 1
icy-metaint: 32768
icy-br: 128
```

To resolve this problem I can use these:

```
<system.net>
  <settings>
  <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />  
  </settings>
</system.net>
```

in my App.config file, but in Windows 8 store app [I cant](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5a8f4b30-a91a-407f-aa6e-7be6ff68a152/how-to-set-useunsafeheaderparsing-of-httpclient).

But MediaElement works just fine with Url(request) mentioned above.

Is there any way to circumvent these restriction?(c++ lib or some).

Thanks.

**

### UPD:

**
I found REST SDK for C++(Casablanca).
Library allows to get response without exception, but still have an issue:

```
http_client client(L"http://173.244.215.162:8300/;stream.nsv");
http_request request(methods::GET);
request.headers().add(L"GET",L"/ HTTP/1.0");
request.headers().add(L"Icy-MetaData",L"1");

client.request(request).then([](http_response response)
{
...
}
```

Response headers appears as part of `responce.body();`
Is there any way to ignore HTTP RFC?
Or How can I make some preProcessing to get right response headers.
Thanks.

### UPD:

Solve this issue with manual headers parsing.
Still watching for better solution.

Comment: I recently wrote a Node.js app and ran into the same issue with the status line.  (`ICY 200 OK` vs `HTTP/1.0 200 OK`)  I got around it by monkey-patching the HTTP client's socket `ondata` callback so that my own code would catch the first bit of data and rewrite that status line before returning it back to the HTTP client.  You might be able to do something similar.  In short, make a small proxy for that data that rewrites the status line before letting the built-in HTTP client handle it for you.  Otherwise, you might have to somehow write your own lightweight HTTP client.